# How to mix css3 transform properties without overriding (in realtime)?

Tags: html, css, transform

Is there any way to combine (mix) css transform properties without overriding? For example there I want to rotate and scale.
http://jsfiddle.net/hyzhak/bmyN3/

## html

```
<div class="item rotate-90 tiny-size">
    Hello World!
</div>
```

## css

```
.rotate-90 {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(90deg);
}
.tiny-size {
    -webkit-transform: scale(0.25, 0.25);
}
```

## PS

I just have a lot of elements and a lot of simple classes to transform view of the elements. And I just want to tune view of them by adding and removing some classes. Combining of all classes doesn't work because it will be hundreds of combinations.

As well I want to do it in realtime.

The number of transformations can be approximately 5 and each of them can hold about 10 states - so just describe all combinations of them with hands give you approximately

```
10*10*10*10*10 = 100000 cases
```

It is a bad solution.

Comment: What's your question? Can you try to describe the actual problem

Comment: @1977 how to mixin css3 transformation without overriding

Comment: Don't forget to click accept on your favorite answer!

Comment: Css variables is way to go.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Here's an attempt at solving the problem with Javascript: http://jsfiddle.net/eGDP7/

I'm using a data attribute on the html to list the classes with transforms that we want to apply:

```
<div class="compoundtransform" data-transformations="scaletrans2, rotatetrans1">Test subject</div>
```

I iterate through the classes and find out what css rules they represent:

```
function getCSSRulesForClass( selector ) {
    var sheets = document.styleSheets;
    var cssRules = [];
    for (var i = 0; i<sheets.length; ++i) {
        var sheet = sheets[i];
        if( !sheet.cssRules ) { continue; }
        for (var j = 0; j < sheet.cssRules.length; ++j ) {
            var rule = sheet.cssRules[j];
            if (rule.selectorText && rule.selectorText.split(',').indexOf(selector) !== -1) {
                var styles = rule.style;
                for( var k = 0; k<styles.length; ++k ) {
                    var style = styles[k];
                    cssRules.push( { 
                        property: style,
                        value: styles[style]
                    } );
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return cssRules;
}
```

I find any transforms and apply the transforms to a matrix:

```
function convertTransformToMatrix( source, transformValue ) {
    var values = transformValue.split(") "); // split into array if multiple values
    var matrix = cloneObject( source );
    for ( var i = 0; i<values.length; ++i ) {
        var value = values[i];
        if( isRotate( value ) ) {
            var rotationValue = cssRotationToRadians( value );
            var cosValue = Math.cos( rotationValue );
            var sinValue = Math.sin( rotationValue );
            var a = matrix.a;
            var b = matrix.b;
            var c = matrix.c;
            var d = matrix.d;
            var tx = matrix.tx;
            var ty = matrix.ty;
            matrix.a = a*cosValue - b*sinValue;
            matrix.b = a*sinValue + b*cosValue;
            matrix.c = c*cosValue - d*sinValue;
            matrix.d = c*sinValue + d*cosValue;
            matrix.tx = tx*cosValue - ty*sinValue;
            matrix.ty = tx*sinValue + ty*cosValue;
        } else if ( isScale( value ) ) {
            var scale = cssScaleToObject( value );
            matrix.a *= scale.x;
            matrix.b *= scale.y;
            matrix.c *= scale.x;
            matrix.d *= scale.y;
            matrix.tx *= scale.x;
            matrix.ty *= scale.y;
        } else if ( isTranslate( value ) ) {
            var translate = cssTranslateToObject( value );
            matrix.tx += translate.x;
            matrix.ty += translate.y;
        }
    }
    return matrix;
}
```

And I, finally, apply that matrix to the node as a transform.

Currently:

- The code is a bit messy
- The CSS parsing is limited to scale(x,y), translate(x,y), and rotate with degree or radian values
- And it would only work with the webkit vendor prefix

I might tidy it up and turn it into a utility if useful to anyone.

Comment: A full utility would be really really awesome. I'm no pro but I'd be glad to try and help you in any way that I can

Comment: I have added javascript utility to github: https://github.com/brejep/additive-transform-js. At the moment, it works for the 2D transform functions - rotate, scale, scaleX, scaleY, translate, translateX, translateY, skew, skewX and skewY.

Comment: Could you compile a comprehensive list of things to improve along with the above?

Comment: Zeaklous, I'll add the improvements it needs to the issues section of the github. Improvements it could do with include: making it work with 3D transform functions and fixing the translate function so it works with all the values in the w3c spec (%, em, etc) and not just pixel values.

Comment: But the `getCSSRulesForClass()` function is a great solution already, I think the same thing can be done for `cssText` as well, as the inline CSS has a higher priority than `cssRules`.

Answer (score 10):

Hmm...as far as I know, you would have to create new class and combine them this way (separated by a space):

```
-webkit-transform: rotate(90deg) scale(0.25, 0.25);
```

Comment: AFAIK also the only way. Note: don't use a `,`

Comment: I hope there are other ways. Because I have a lot of simple classes with the transformation and the sum of all of combinations of them will be a really huge number

Comment: Yeah, you definitely want to try SASS or LESS (see Zeaklous's answer) if you can. Those scripts are just totally awesome for many reasons. @EugeneKrevenets

Comment: @m59 yes, I already use SASS - but I need to update classes in realtime. So it's not about preprocessing

Answer (score 8):

The way I get around this issue is to add a wrapper class around the one I want. For example, I have the wrapper which has its position set via javascript, and then the internal which is is affected by css animations - both on the transform property.

I know adding DOM nodes isn't ideal but it circumvents the script-heavy solution and lets the browser optimise the animations and transitions as it would normally.

Comment: Wrapping is probably the best option.

Comment: 8 years later, using a wrapper is still the best solution -- less work and sans JS. I've been doing this w SVG animations, putting a <g> around elements and applying a separate transform there.

Answer (score 4):

Currently there is no way to do this, it only accepts one command for `transform` at a time and cannot add or subtract like you'd like. Thus you'll have to add or remove a class depending on what the first and second type is and write a custom `transform` for that element

Using a CSS preprocessor language like SASS or LESS could make combining transitions easier, the following allows for any number of `transition`s to be combined into one, but requires being told which ones to add (this is SCSS)

```
.item {
  width:500px;
  height:500px;
  font-size:150px;
  background:blue;
}

$firstTransform: rotate(90deg);
$secondTransform: scale(0.25, 0.25);

@mixin transform($transform...) {
  -webkit-transform: $transform;
     -moz-transform: $transform;
      -ms-transform: $transform;
       -o-transform: $transform;
          transform: $transform;
}
.rotate-90 {
  @include transform($firstTransform);
}
.tiny-size {
  @include transform($secondTransform);
}
.both {
  @include  transform($firstTransform $secondTransform);
}
```

[**Demo**](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/tukcq)

Really the only way to do it currently would be to use javascript, essentially adding a class with a transform, saving a variable of that class' transforms, removing the class and doing the same with another class, then combine the two matrices of the class' transforms. **EDIT:** See [brejep's javascript answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20167239/how-to-mix-css3-transform-properties-without-overriding-in-realtime/20200863#20200863) for more on this approach

Comment: Ok what about if you will have 5 kinds of transformation with 5-10 states?
I have shown simple case just to describe case not to show count of transformations

Comment: @EugeneKrevenets Just updated the SASS solution to accept any number of arguments. As for the actual adding/subtracting of transforms, I'll have to work on the matrix math when I have more time

Comment: In my case it leads to 100k combination of transformation. So it doesn't help

Comment: @EugeneKrevenets I do in fact realize this. I'm attempting to provide the best solution that CSS has to offer, what you want simply isn't possible. As I mentioned I'll try to work out a js solution when I have more time

Comment: I really interesting to know about your solution, so if you will do any working experiments please share with us. :)

Comment: @EugeneKrevenets brejep posted an answer using the js approach. I may work to improve it, the potential for an application using the approach is great

Answer (score 2):

Instead of rotate and scale you could use the matrix function.

```
transform: matrix(a, b, c, d, tx, ty);
```

In the example given, I believe the following would produce the desired result:

```
transform: matrix(0,-0.25,0.25,0,0,0);
```

For an explanation of matrix calculations:

- http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_transformation#Examples_of_linear_transformation_matrices

And some useful tools exist for calculating these matrices as CSS, such as:

- http://www.boogdesign.com/examples/transforms/matrix-calculator.html

Comment: yeah. Thanks! I know how to work linear matrix but - I have such a case where a designer will be updating information about transformation not me - and he prefers to tune CSS parameters for each kind of the transformation.

Comment: Fair enough. I'm not sure there is a way to enlighten designers about this stuff. :)

Comment: Just re-read and I see what you mean. I think any transform in CSS is really describing a matrix even if you just use the scale, or skew or rotate functions. So if you scale(0.5,0.5), you are actually saying to the browser matrix(0.5, 0, 0, 0.5, 0, 0). So any rotations will be overriden. Because CSS is all about styles overriding one another this can't be solved in CSS alone. So pre-processor or Javascript are only possibilities. My attempt at a javascript solution will appear soon...

Answer (score 1):

One thing you could do is get the computed transform style in JS and concatenate your secondary transform value:

**HTML**

```
<div class="rotate-scale"></div>
```

**CSS**

```
.rotate-scale {
   transform: rotate(90deg);
}
```

**JS**

```
var el = document.querySelector('.rotate-scale'),
    // rotation will get the transform value declared in css
    rotation = window.getComputedStyle(el).getPropertyValue('transform');

el.style.transform = rotation + 'scale(0.25, 0.25)';
```