# CSS3 handling multiple values for transform property

Tags: html, css, transform

Is there any way to add value on transform property on css3 using class, without affecting the other values?

```
.myclass {
    transform: rotate(40deg) scale(1);
}

.scale {
    transform: scale(4);
}
```

---

```
<div class="myclass scale">Hello World</div>
```

Comment: I think the short answer is no, see this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20167239/how-to-mix-css3-transform-properties-without-overriding-in-realtime

Comment: thanks. almost found solution on the article you gave

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately the answer would be no. To perform multiple, independent animations online, a better solution to research could be the GreenSock Animation Platform, or GSAP. http://www.greensock.com/get-started-js/

If is a .js tool set to help with various animations and from the looks of it (haven't dove in fully yet) it seems quite fast and very impressive.

Comment: thanks.. looking forward for this library. it well take a lot of changes then. i rather use this on my next project. for now my simple solution for my problem was to change concept :(