# css rotate a transformed object

Tags: html, css, transform, css-animations

html

```
<div class="camera">
  <div class="dreid">
    <div class="planet1"></div>
    <div class="planet2"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

css

```
.camera {
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  -webkit-perspective: 800;
  -webkit-perspective-origin: 50% 700px;
}
.dreid {
  width:220px;
  height:220px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  border: 1px solid black;
  margin: 60px auto;
  -webkit-transform: rotateX(45deg);
  -webkit-animation-name: spin;
  -webkit-animation-duration: 10s;
  -webkit-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
  -webkit-animation-timing-function: linear;  

}

@-webkit-keyframes spin {
  from {
    -webkit-transform:rotate(0deg);
  }
  to {
    -webkit-transform:rotate(360deg);
  }
}
.planet1 {
  position:absolute;
  top:0;
  left:0;
  width:50px;
  height:50px;
  background:red;
  border-radius:50%;
}
.planet2 {
  position: absolute;
  top:170px;
  left:170px;
  width:50px;
  height:50px;
  background:red;
  border-radius:50%;
}
```

as you can see i tried to apply perspective to a circle before rotating it (sort of like in a planetary system). the problem is, the animation bit seem to overwrite the transform bit that i set up with -perspective and -transform:rotate. is it possible to get it done with pure css?

edit: [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/nBvVt/1/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One element cannot have multiple `transform`s applied to it. Since you have a `transform` in the animation, it will override your older one

Your options are to either add a container element and apply the animation to that or to manually add the original transform to the animation's transform

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/Zeaklous/nBvVt/2/) of the second option

See [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20167239/how-to-mix-css3-transform-properties-without-overriding-in-realtime) for more information

Comment: On a side note you could use pseudo elements instead of inner elements if you wanted to

Comment: i tried adding the -transform:rotateX to my "spin" function, but that resulted in perspective overwriting the spinning. not sure i understood properly though.

Comment: ah answered too quick. yeah thats exactly what i meant! but i was so dumb as to delete my -transform inside the container ans just added it to my animation. thank you very much!

Comment: false an element can have more tha one trasform applied to it, if it's done in one line, see here http://jsfiddle.net/ELyTU/4/

Comment: @Olumide That's not at all what I'm saying. I'm saying an element cannot have more than one *separate instance of `transform`* applied at once, not several *properties of a `transform`*